# Discord.js v14 button interaction failed

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am having issue with my buttons and discord saying the interaction has failed. I believe this issue has something to do with the collector however I am not entirely sure what that problem may be. I am thinking that the problem is with the collector that i named mapBanCollector because I put in a console.log('The mapBanCollector is working!') and the console has never once printed that message I've attempted to fix this for a while now but I am very stuck and would appreciate some help if anyone knows the cause of this.

```
      const shuffledQueue = [...queue].sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
      const captains = [shuffledQueue[0], shuffledQueue[1]];
      const players = shuffledQueue.slice(2);
      const shuffledCaptains = captains.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
      // console.log(captains)

      const team1Captain = captains[0]; 
      const mapPool = [
        'Bind',
        'Haven',
        'Split',
        'Ascent',
        'Icebox',
        'Breeze',
        'Fracture',
        'Pearl',
        'Lotus'
      ];
      
      const MAX_MAPS_TO_BAN = 1; 
      
      let mapBanCount = 0;
      
      const mapBanButtons = [];
      mapPool.forEach((map, index) => {
        const banButton = new ButtonBuilder()
          .setCustomId(`ban_${map}`)
          .setLabel(map)
          .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger)
          .setDisabled(false);
        banButton.layout = index < 3 ? 1 : index < 6 ? 2 : 3;
        mapBanButtons.push(banButton);
        //console.log(banButton);
      });
      
      const actionRow1 = new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(mapBanButtons.slice(0, 3));
        
      const actionRow2 = new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(mapBanButtons.slice(3, 6));
      
      const actionRow3 = new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(mapBanButtons.slice(6, 9));
      
      const mapBanPhase1Embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle('Map Ban Phase')
        .setDescription(`${team1Captain.username}, please ban a map.`)
        .addFields({
          name: 'Maps',
          value: mapPool.join('\n'),
        });
      
      const testing = await interaction.editReply({
        embeds: [mapBanPhase1Embed],
        components: [actionRow1, actionRow2, actionRow3],
      });

      console.log(testing)
      
      const mapBanCollector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
        componentType: 'BUTTON',
        time: 180000,
        filter: (i) => {
          console.log(`Filtering for user ${team1Captain.id}...`);
          return i.user.id === team1Captain.id;
        }
      });
      
      mapBanCollector.on('collect', async (buttonInteraction) => {

        console.log('The mapBanCollector is working!')

        if (team1Captain.id !== buttonInteraction.user.id) {
          return;
        }
        if (mapBanCount >= MAX_MAPS_TO_BAN) {
          return;
        }
      
        const bannedMap = banButton.customId.split('_')[1];

        console.log(`${team1Captain.username} has banned ${bannedMap}.`);
      
        
        buttonInteraction.update({
          components: [new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(buttonInteraction.component.setDisabled(true))]
        });
      
        
        mapBanCount++;
        mapPool.splice(mapPool.indexOf(bannedMap), 1);
        mapBanPhase1Embed.setDescription(`${team1Captain.username} has banned ${bannedMap}.`);
        if (mapBanCount < MAX_MAPS_TO_BAN) {
          mapBanPhase1Embed.addFields({
            name: 'Maps',
            value: mapPool.join('\n'),
          });
          await interaction.update({
            embeds: [mapBanPhase1Embed],
            components: [actionRow1, actionRow2, actionRow3],
          });
        } else {
          mapBanPhase1Embed.removeFields(0, 1);
          await interaction.update({
            embeds: [mapBanPhase1Embed],
            components: [],
          });
        }
      });
      
      mapBanCollector.on('end', async () => {
        console.log("Captain A has banned " + bannedMap + ".");
        if (mapPool.length === 1) {
          await interaction.update(`${team1Captain.username}, you banned the last map, ${mapPool[0]}.`);
          return;
        }
      
        const team1MapBan = mapPool[Math.floor(Math.random() * mapPool.length)];
        mapPool.splice(mapPool.indexOf(team1MapBan), 1);
      
        const team2MapBan = mapPool[Math.floor(Math.random() * mapPool.length)];
        mapPool.splice(mapPool.indexOf(team2MapBan), 1);
      
        const team1Map = mapPool[Math.floor(Math.random() * mapPool.length)];
        mapPool.splice(mapPool.indexOf(team1Map), 1);
      
        const team2Map = mapPool[0];
      
        const mapEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
          .setTitle('Map Selection')
          .setDescription(`Team 1 banned ${team1MapBan}\nTeam 2 banned ${team2MapBan}\n\n${team1Captain.username} selected ${team1Map}\n${captains[1].username} selected ${team2Map}`)
          .setImage(`https://i.imgur.com/${team1Map}.png`);
      
        await interaction.update({
          embeds: [mapEmbed],
          allowedMentions: { repliedUser: false },
        });
      });
```

I did not paste the full code of the command because this is just what I believe the problem is but if anyone would like to look at the full command code just let me know and I will edit the question. Thank you in advance to anyone taking the time out of their day to help me with this!

The bot is suppose to allow the captain of team 1 to ban a single map from the map pool and afterwards it should send a message in chat saying which map was banned. However, the buttons do not work they just say interaction failed when clicked on and I believe that the mapBanCollector is not turning on at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a bunch of different issues, first of them:

> const mapBanCollector = interaction.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({

This piece of code is trying to create a `MESSAGE COMPONENT` [collector](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#basic-message-component-collector) on a `CHANNEL`. You need to provide the `interaction.reply()` message after it was fetched instead.

Second: your collector doesn't acknowledge the reaction, only edits the button here:

> buttonInteraction.update({
> components: [new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(buttonInteraction.component.setDisabled(true))]
> });

You need to acknowledge the reaction to stop the "interaction failed" errors. You can do so by adding this at the top of your collector:

```
await buttonInteraction.deferReply()
```